# Restart after updating?

Tags: elementary-project

So I have to ask the question.

More often than not lately, EOS is wanting to restart the system after applying updates from the app center.

That's seems very un-Linux-ish to me.

Why is this happening?

Comment: The need for a restart is determined by what parts of the system are being updated. If it’s kernel or service-related, restarts are sometimes necessary. If it’s just applications, then a restart is not required 